# Autogenerate Serial Number

Tags: excel

I want to Auto generate serial number.

```
Student Name Serial number Address Group Section Student ID

Monir 07001 Dhaka,Bangladesh Science B SC001B
```

When I enter a Student name it will automatically generate its Serial number in the place of Serial number .After that if i save it again enter any new student it will generate the next serial number automatically.

How do i can do it. Please help me.

Comment: After whcih pattern should the serial number be generated?

Comment: It should be 07001 for the first one then again 07002 for the next one.After some entry if i save it and again enter any new student name then it should auto generated in the serial number cell.Let say if i enter two serial number for ten student  and save it.When i open that sheet again and try enter any new student name then in the serial number cell it should be automatically generate the next serial number.So that i do not need to memorize the serial number for the next student.Please give me the solution in the excel.

Comment: From this and your previous post, I suspect you should be using a database, rather than Excel.

Answer (score 3):

If I understood your question correctly the excel-solution is rather easy.

Add the serial number for the first student by hand (07001) and fill the remaining serial number fields (the ones below) with the following formula:

Formula: =IF(ISBLANK(A2),"",B1+1)
With A2 = cell to the left and B1 = cell above

R1C1 Notation: =IF(ISBLANK(RC[-1]),"",R[-1]C+1)

**Edit:** To "add" a leading 0 to the number, you need to set the number format of your serial number to the following custom format: 000000

Comment: This will not generate "07002", but "7002".

Comment: OK, but it's a minor change to make the formula =IF(ISBLANK(RC[-1]),"",Text(R[-1]C+1, "000000"))

Comment: Daves formula works and I added another approach to "add" a leading zero.