# Auto-generated username

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I've been trying to search to find the answer to this question as I'm sure it's been asked a dozen or more times, but for the life of me I can't find an answer.

I've got a basic form with 2 text fields...firstname, lastname and a username field that is read-only.

I'm looking for a way to populate the username dependent on the entries in the firstname lastname fields. I'm guessing jquery or javascript can get this done...but like I said above....having a heck of a time trying to find some examples.

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Autogenerate Serial Number](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1496642/autogenerate-serial-number)

Comment: Just take a couple of letters from the first name and prefix them to the surname. Just string handling

Comment: Hi Rod!  Welcome to SO.  If you can add the basics of what you've done so far, that will help people answer your question.  Have you been able to extract the data from the text fields, for example?  Do you have a sense of how to handle the data once you've extracted it?  When would you like this to happen - as soon as the users have entered text, after they click a button, or something else?

Comment: Take substrings of the first and last name, then append them to one another ?

Comment: *"having a heck of a time trying to find some examples"* maybe because... it's such a simple task? `var stringC = stringA + stringB`

Answer (score 0):

Concatenate the two inuput values of the firtname and lastname inputs:

```
$('input[name=username]').val($('input[name=firstname]').val()+$('input[name=lastname]').val()).attr('disabled','');
```

Answer (score 0):

Include jQuery.

```
<script type="text/javascript">
     //setup an event to toggle this here, like a submit, click, or similar
     $('#usernameId').html($('#firstnameID').val() +' '+$('#lastnameID').val())
</script>
```

Where I used #usernameID you'd want to substitute the id of the username field.